# Array is not printing out through cout

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I am running into some trouble trying to print out this code. I have a function that generates a search space with ranges 1 to 8. But when I try to output it, the program quits on me.

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

char yOrN;
int answer;
const int LENGTH=4096;
int guess[LENGTH];

void searchspace(int guesses[],int length){
int count = 0;
for(int i=1; i=8;i++){
    for(int j=1; j=8; j++){
        for(int k=1;k=8;k++){
            for(int l=1;l=8;l++){
                guesses[count]=1000*i+100*j+10*k+l;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

int main(){
searchspace(guess,LENGTH);
for(int i = 0; i<4096;i++){
    cout<<guess[i]<<endl;
}
 }
```

Comment: First things first... do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Use the `<` key more.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "I don't know what the hell is going on so please edit my code"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop (and the others)

```
for(int j=1; j=8; j++)
```

finishes when `j=8` evaluates to `true`. Which is always.

Did you mean:

```
for(int j=1; j<=8; j++)
```

Comment: The == won't work, since it won't run the first time. j==8 evaluates to false on the first iteration because j is initially 1.

Comment: You could use `j!=8` if you like, but `j<=8` is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loops are all wrong, e.g. you need to change:

```
for(int i=1; i=8;i++){
```

to

```
for(int i=1; i<=8;i++){
```

and similarly for the others.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code:

- for loops
- yOrn , answer were not used, hence removed
- removed ';' after #include

here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int LENGTH=4096;
int guess[LENGTH];

void searchspace(int guesses[],int length){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=8;i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=8; j++){
            for(int k=1;k<=8;k++){
                for(int l=1;l<=8;l++){
                    guesses[count]=1000*i+100*j+10*k+l;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    searchspace(guess,LENGTH);
    for(int i = 0; i<4096;i++){
        cout<<guess[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

I compiled and ran it - works perfectly ( at least I assume that is what you wanted to do).

Comment: Yeah the problem was the i<=8.